# Converting JSON to XML for SOAP Webservice

Tags: php, web-services

I am new to webservices,One problem I am facing which is like Input is in JSON format but I need to convert that to XML and pass..Can somebody suggest me on the same

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert JSON data to array. Then just conver the array to simple XML. Here is the sample code for this:

```
//JSON to Array
$arrayData = json_decode($jsonData, true);
//Array to XML
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($arrayData, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
$xmlData = $xml->asXML();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you.But it doesnt solves the problem, actually what I need is, through SOAP call, application previously expecting JSON format and which was working fine that time, Now with the latest version of application it is expection XML format, I converted but still output I am not getting

Comment: It might be the problem of you application version. The answer was just to convert any JSON format to XML format. You can also try this code for any test JSON data and convert it to XML. It will surely work. SO now what you need to do is post the SOAP error.

Comment: Actually,the problem is code is written to get JSON as input and display in application.But now the application is expecting XML format which I converted with your help.Thank you.Now I am not able to display that, It is just basically an auto incremented Id from one application to another application through SOAP